# Securing an API on the same domain/server as the website making the calls?

Tags: html, ajax, security

If your API and Website making ajax calls to that API are on the same server (even domain), how would you secure that API?

I only want requests from the same server to be allowed! No remote requests from any other domain, I already have SSL installed does this mean I am safe?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want only requests from localhost or only requests from the same domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some confusion that I want to help you clear up.

By the very fact that you are talking about "making Ajax calls" you are talking about your application making remote requests to your server. Even if your website is served from the same domain you are making a remote request.

> I only want requests from the same server to be allowed!

Therein lies the problem. You are not talking about making a request from server-to-server. You are talking about making a request from client-to-server (Ajax), so you cannot use IP restrictions (unless you know the IP address of every client that will access your site).

Restricting Ajax requests does not need to be any different than restricting other requests. How do you keep unauthorized users from accessing "normal" web pages? Typically you would have the user authenticate, create a user session on the server, pass a session cookie back tot he client that is then submitted on every request, right?  All that stuff works for Ajax requests too.

If your API is exposed on the internet there is nothing you can do to stop others from trying to make requests against it (again, unless you know all of the IPs of allowed clients). So you have to have server-side control in place to authorize remote calls from your allowed clients.

Oh, and having TLS in place is a step in the right direction. I am always amazed by the number of developers that think they can do without TLS. But TLS alone is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `request_referer` in your HTTP headers. That tell you where the request came from.

Comment: Easily faked. Not a secure method.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to secure it from.

**Third parties getting their visitors to request data from your API using the credentials those visitors have on your site**

Browsers [will protect you automatically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) unless you take steps to [disable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) that [protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

**Third parties getting their visitors to request changes to your site using your API and the visitors' credentials**

Nothing Ajax specific about this. Implement the usual defences against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

**Third parties requesting data using their own client**

Again, nothing Ajax specific about this. You can't prevent the requests being made. You need authentication/authorisation (e.g. password protection).

> I already have SSL installed does this mean I am safe

No. That protects data from being intercepted enroute. It doesn't prevent other people requesting the data, or accessing it from the end points.

Answer (score 0):

you can check ip address, if You want accept request  only from same server, place .htaccess in api directory or in virtualhost configuration directive, to allow only 127.0.0.1 or localhost. Configuration is based on what webserver You have.

Comment: The question says that Ajax is being used. It almost certainly means "browsers visiting the website" and not "the website". The browsers will usually be running on other computers with different ip addresses, so this won't help.

Comment: yes, my fault ... 
`no remote requests` and `making ajax calls to that API` is mission impossible. Maybe you can set some api keys like google. and allow access if key is valid to that domain.